# Set Region Content per View in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

My scenario:

- I have a "Shell" ViewModel
- In the Shell, I have a ContentControl that loads / navigates another ViewModel
- I have an Area at the bottom of the shell where I need to add some controls (different per ViewModel)
- I am Using ViewModel first approach
- I am NOT using PRISM

  [Scenario Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESnWI.png)

My ViewModel has buttons (add, edit, delete... the usual) which works fine. I need to move these buttons into that  bottom section (as in the image).

Problem is, the buttons will be **out of scope of my ViewModel** since they're moving into the Shell.

Idea that I had:

- Bind the bottom section to a Custom class. Then on each view, set the DataTemplate of this custom class with all it's controls

I tried this, but it seems that the new DataTemplate on a view never gets reflected.

Any ideas on the DataTemplates can work?
Or
How can I define different controls in the bottom section per ViewModel, but the events they fire must be inscope of my current ViewModel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution eventually was to simply put the "commands section" within the view model at the bottom instead of in the Shell view model

See the [New Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8sPZ.png)